# Change Submenu URL in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I need to change sub menu URLs in Joomla.

[image]

In the above example, if I click Graphic design, then the URL showing:

www.mydomain.com/moreservices/graphicdesign.html

But I don't need "moreservices" in the above URL.

The same way, suppose if I click the Walkthrough, the URL is

www.mydomain.com/moreservices/3d/walkthrough.html

Here I don't need "moreservices/3d/" from the URL. How can I change URL?

Comment: Have you tried using an extension like sh404SEF ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy fix for this because that is how Joomla builds a URL from a menu item. The only way to get rid of the parent menu item is to create a new menu where you will move all of the sub menu items to. They have to be top level items in this new menu so that the URLs look like you want them to. You do not need to put this menu in a module, it does not need to display anywhere, it just needs to exists.

Next, once you have moved all the sub menus to this new menu, you will create new menu item aliases for each of them. A menu alias inherits its URL from the menu item it redirects to so your URLs should look like you want them to.